# In prestashop at which file cash on delivery module is calling

Tags: prestashop

I need to know the location of file from where cash on delivery module is calling inside the choose your payment method checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the template display on payment choices page of the module "cash on delivery" here : /modules/cashondelivery/views/templates/hook/payment.tpl
If you user older version of PrestaShop, this template is here : /modules/cashondelivery/payment.tpl

NB: If you want to modify this template for your theme is better to overwrite it by put it directly in the "modules" folder of your theme.